# How is the acces control not valid YAML

Tags: php, yaml, symfony

I have a question, i am following the doc of symfony and i am at the security part.

The first bit is going good but when i am at the acces control part i get stuck.

It says this:

> The file "C:\xampp\htdocs\zelfstudie\framework-standard-edition\app/config\security.yml" does not contain valid YAML in C:\xampp\htdocs\zelfstudie\framework-standard-

---

This my `security.yml`:

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html

security:
    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        default:
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic: ~

    access_control:
        # require ROLE_ADMIN for /admin*
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # http_basic: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

            # form_login: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html
```

Comment: seems the standard initial yaml of the security files. Howenever try to vaildate the content with this service http://www.freecodeformat.com/yaml-validator.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have:

```
access_control:
    - { ... }
    main:
        anonymous: ~
```

This is mixing YAML lists and dictionaries which is not allowed. I guess `main` is a firewall name so it should probably be:

```
security:
    ...
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

    firewalls:
        main:
            anonymous: ~
```